# how do you globally install a file as the root/administrator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

when I try "npm install -g jshint", I get the following readout.

```
user-MacBook-Pro:~ davidgoldberg$ npm install -g jshint
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jshint'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jshint']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jshint',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jshint',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "jshint"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/davidgoldberg
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jshint
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jshint
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jshint'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/davidgoldberg/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'd love to get error sorted out.  "npm install jshint" works fine, by the way.  ultimately, I need help downloading jshint for use in "sublimelint-jshint" on sublime tex 3.

Comment: Have you tried running it as an Admin?

Comment: "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator" is the issue if you're trying to install globally.

Comment: how do I run as an admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to be root to install globally with `npm`, so try:

```
sudo npm -g install jshint
```